# Challenges in Using GradientTexture for Array Transmission in Material Shader

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, cesiumjs

I initially intended to use a uniform array variable in ms. However, since the type of uniform does not support array types, I resorted to using `gradientTexture` to convey the array. I employed the following method for transmission, but it fails to correctly pass the array. I would appreciate an analysis of the reason behind this.

```js
let gradientData = new Float32Array([
    -0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, -0.5
]);

let gradientTexture = new Cesium.Texture({
    context: viewer.scene.context,
    pixelFormat: Cesium.PixelFormat.RG,
    pixelDatatype: Cesium.PixelDatatype.FLOAT,
    flipY: false,
    source: {
        arrayBufferView: gradientData,
        width: 2,
        height: 2,
    }
});

let material = new Cesium.Material({
    fabric: {
        type: 'Flow',
        uniforms: {
            image: './blank.jpg',
            time: 0.0,
            gradientMap: {
                type: 'sampler2D',
                value: gradientTexture
            },
        },
        source: `
        czm_material czm_getMaterial(czm_materialInput materialInput) {
                czm_material material = czm_getDefaultMaterial(materialInput);
                // the value is not correct
                vec2 gradientOri = texture2D(gradientMap, materialInput.st).rg;
                vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
                vec2 direction = center - gradientOri;
                float length = length(direction);
                vec2 normalizedDirection = normalize(direction);
                vec2 newCoords = materialInput.st + normalizedDirection * time * 0.05 * length;
                // vec2 newCoords = materialInput.st;
                material.diffuse = texture2D(image, newCoords).rgb;
                return material;
            }
                `
    }
});
```

I am looking for a feasible method to receive array data types in Material Shader. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: The is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.